# Remove table row after post 1 item inline table in vueJS

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have inline table from database connection with vueJS. the plan is to make a duplicate of one of the rows. row was successfully duplicated with `this.array.push (... ...)`

but when I want to remove it in a way this `ar.array.splice (index (from row), 1)`
the deleted ones are the top or bottom, not the row in the index that was clicked on

1. [duplicate result](https://pasteboard.co/J73TwCN.png)
2. [after click button remove row duplicate](http://after%20click%20button%20remove%20row%20duplicate) antigua country which was previously duplicated instead disappears
3. [deleted and even antartica row, while the one i removed was row antigua](https://pasteboard.co/J73VWBw.png)

code:

```
  public duplicate(){
    this.countries.push({ 
      name: this.multipleSelection[0].name, 
      code: this.multipleSelection[0].code, 
      currencyId: this.multipleSelection[0].currencyId,
      currencyName: this.multipleSelection[0].currencyName,
      duplicate: true
    })
  }

  public cancelDuplicate(item, index){
    this.countries.splice(index, 1)
    console.log(index)
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use findIndex to splice arr

this.countries.splice(this.countries.findIndex(e => e === index),1)